# How to ignore a set of Mac addresses in dhcpd.conf?

Tags: networking, configuration, dhcp, isc-dhcp

Is it possible in dhcpd.conf to ignore requests from a set of MAC addresses?

Something like this:

```
host vminstances {
    hardware ethernet d0:0d:*;
    ignore booting;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
class "ignored" {
        match if substring(hardware,1,4) = 00:02;
}


pool {
        deny members of "ignored";
        range 192.168.172.100 192.168.172.149;
        }
```

Comment: Do you need the 'range' set in the pool? I would have thought this was irrelevant.

Comment: The range directive is just one way of defining a pool.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but if you're trying to ignore based on MAC address then why specify a range? Is it necessary?

Comment: The range relates to the pool of adresses to be assigned by the dhcp server, it does not relate to the filtering. Any client not matching the mac adresses defined in the class "ignored" will get adresses from this range.

Comment: Shouldn't it read "substring(hardware,1,2)" for the first 2 bytes of the MAC address?

Answer (score 8):

From [this thread](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2010-July/012024.html) on the mailing list, another option to block specific hosts is:

```
class "black-hole" {
    match substring (hardware, 1, 6);
    # deny booting;
    ignore booting;
}
subclass "black-hole" <MAC-ADDRESS-TO_IGNORE>;
```

The thread also says that the difference between `ignore` and `deny` is that the later logs the request whereas the former does not.