# how to block incoming DHCP DISCOVERY messages

Tags: iptables, firewall, centos6, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

I'm running ISC DHCP deamon on centOS and want to block unwanted(by clients MAC address) discovery messages before they reach dhcpd.

how can I do this with iptables or anything else?

Comment: If you've got "unwanted clients" on your network I'd recommend blocking them on your infrastructure (switches) and/or remove them physically. Disabling their DHCP doesn't prevent them from using a static address.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux netfilter firewall has the ability to match on MAC address and then simply filter the DHCP protocol (UDP port 67,68) messages:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -p udp --sport 67:68 --dport 67:68  -j DROP
```

Although a better alternative is probably to configure your DHCP server to ignore requests from certain MAC addresses as described in [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/91643/37681)

Comment: can I match wildcard mac  11:22:33:* ?

Comment: I think the required form is `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` but I don't know if `xx:xx:xx:*:*:*` works. Why don't you go and test that?

Comment: still getting discovery messages after adding following rule : sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55  -j DROP

Comment: You did replace the sample MAC address with the actual MAC you're trying to block, right?

Comment: yes I did.I found that all the requests are from same mac addr(GW dhcp server is using) so, inspecting just layer 2 mac will not help. it needs to inspect dhcp message headers.

Comment: iptables can match, but it's probably too late with ISC DHCP server: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00378 . RAW sockets bypass iptables.